# Gulp Vue JS not compiling conflict on style tag

Tags: gulp, browserify, vue.js

I'm trying to compile vue component using gulp and browserify. I'm using vueify to suit my needs.

Here's my code looks like.

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}'];

<style>
    .layout-wrapper { width: ${ canvas.test }; }
</style>

module.exports = {
    props: ['theme_id'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            canvas: {
                test: '12345px',
                content: {},
```

The problem is, it's not compiling. But when I tried

```
    .layout-wrapper { width: ${ '12345px' }; }
```

It does worked though. Is there a problem calling the data object?

Comment: I don't think you can put a style tag under scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the example .vue file in the documentation:

https://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#Single-File-Components

The format should be:

```
<style>

</style>
<template>

</template>
<script>
  module.exports = {

  }
</script>
```

There is also not a way to use Vue variables in the `style` section.  You need to use them inline in the template:

```
<div :style="{width:canvas.test}">
```

If you want to use a different language in the style section add a `lang` attribute.  That can enable you to use variables if you know any other css languages:

```
<style lang="scss">
  $canvaswidth = '123px';
  .layout-wrapper {width: $canvaswidth}
```